# Internet Explorer 11, how to STYLE readonly?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, readonly

i am double checking if everything is good with my website with also other browsers.

I noticed that in Chrome i can style readonly but in Internet Explorer you can't style it.

I normally have disabled on input fields but this readonly fields need to be readonly for putting it into the database.

If it's not possible. I want the readonly input not to be focused in with the mouse click. Because i now have a input field readonly with a placeholder. If i click inside the readonly input the text dissapears. So the input can change if i click inside it. Can that be prevented if my first question can't be done?

Thanks for your time, i appreciate it.

HTML readonly (need it to be readonly because i have to POST it)

```
<input id='overNightRate' type='text' name='overNightRate' class='form-control disabledDesign' placeholder="Bedrag word berekent" readonly/>
```

CSS

```
.disabledDesign:read-only{background-color:#003c85;
  color: white;
opacity: 1;}
```

And i have more input fields which are the same but just calculate the sum of something. And that needs to be readonly also because it needs to store that input data to the database

Comment: How are you trying to style it? Please edit your question to include HTML and CSS. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: use disabled and not readonly attribute if it's meant not to be clickable nor usable `<input placeholder="hello" disabled />` https://jsbin.com/sekorujilu/1/edit?html,css,js,output *jsbin can be run from IE11*

Comment: @disinfor I am now updating my answer with more details

Comment: in which case do you have a placeholder ? in which do you need to update the value of that field ? You can master that on server side. Just update the field that needs to be, otherwise , You should maybe not mind that much about the few IE11 users ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr I have a placeholder like ("Price is being calculated"). And that needs to be readonly because i save that input data to the database

Comment: @G-Cyr Can you make a answer on how i can master it on the server side like your saying, i did edit my question with examples HTML and CSS

Comment: okay , that makes sense to me, you could use an hidden input to update that value, and use the readonly for the show.

Comment: @G-Cyr Hmmm oke, not really a nice solution but oke. If it have to be like this , so be it. Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: @G-Cyr Answer below is the right answer. Thanks for your time

Comment: okay, i guess i misunderstood : https://jsbin.com/cewaquvade/1/edit?html,css,js,output placeholder value still dissapear once cliked inside in IE was this not one of your issue ? Should i mention i run a genuine IE11 ;) @disinfor

Comment: @G-Cyr I tested it in a BrowserStack instance of IE11. I used to run a VirtualBox container with IE11, but it was sooooooo slow.

Comment: @G-Cyr Yeah that's still a problem actually. But the disabled design that have makes it clear that its a disabled input field so nobody will click inside but, if you know a answer that would be great also. Will check your jsbin in a while.

Comment: @disinfor You may use `pointer-events:none;` on the readonly input to avoid also the click effect on  IE11 too. It should then fully answer the question ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr Thanks man! Now its perfect! I will like 3 things of you so you get more points. Have a nice day/night!

Comment: @G-Cyr updated the answer to include `pointer-events: none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs to be `readonly`, I believe IE 11 supports the attr selector:

```css
.disabledDesign[readonly='readonly'] {
  background-color: #003c85;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input id='overNightRate' type='text' name='overNightRate' class='form-control disabledDesign' placeholder="Bedrag word berekent" readonly="readonly" />
```

Edit: Tested on IE11 and works as expected.